# Xamarin iOS HttpRequestException "Connection reset by peer" on web requests after updating app

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

We have a self-hosted Apple Enterprise Developer based iOS app that was released around six weeks ago. We're working on the next version of the app and are seeing problems when people update to the new test version. An HttpRequestException is thrown with a "Connection reset by peer" message whenever calls over HTTPS that include a bearer token are made. The call stack shown in the MS App Center error report provides little info to go on.

`Main thread
System.Net.Sockets
Socket.Receive (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags socketFlags)
System.Net.Sockets
NetworkStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size)`

The initial web request to sign the user in appears to be working. It is the only request that doesn't include a bearer token in the headings. All subsequent requests in a given session cause this exception to be thrown.

We have found that users can resolve the error by removing the currently released version of the app from their phone before installing the new version. The error no longer occurs in the new version once that is done. We've also received a couple of reports of users getting the error even without upgrading the version of the app. It seems to occur for those users after not having used the app in a while.

We have tried to reproduce the error by following the same steps of installing the new test version on top of the released version on our devices and it works fine.

Our project manager has the issue on her personal device. She has been testing new versions without upgrading to see if the exception is no longer thrown. We have tried the following to resolve the problem without success:

- Removed all local caching of previous web request results and bearer tokens, forcing live requests at all times
- Switching from the iOS NSUrlSession implementation of HttpClient back to the default Xamarin managed implementation
- Verifying the HttpClient base URI and individual request URIs are what are expected
- Verifying the bearer token value has been assigned to the HttpClient Authorization default headers when the calls are made

Has anyone had this happen to them, or maybe can shed some light on possible causes of this exception being thrown? Thanks a ton for any help provided. It is driving us crazy!

Here's an example of one of the request calls. The HttpClient property is a static instance that is used for the lifetime of the app. The SaveContext property is a bool that is used to enable/disable context saving to test performing the requests in background threads without saving the context. Both options have been tried and had no impact on the error occurring. The HttpClient BaseAddress property has the API uri root assigned to it. The uri passed to GetAsync is a relative uri.

```
HttpResponseMessage serverResponse = await HttpClient.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(SaveContext);
```

Here's more of the setup:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler {
    AllowAutoRedirect = true, AutomaticDecompression = 
    DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip, 
    MaxAutomaticRedirections = 20
};

var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(JsonSerializerHelper.JsonEncoding));
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```